# How to find file that has read permissions from root directory?

Tags: shell, find, cp

I am trying to find files with read permissions from root directory and save them under `/home/student/abc` direcory:

```
find / -type f -perm a+r -exec cp /home/student/abc {} +
```

but it shows me the error:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do not post screenshots of text. Copy-paste the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, fixes the cp parameter order and limits to just root filesystem rather than trying to traverse /proc and the like.

```
find / -xdev -type f -perm a+r -exec cp {} /home/student/abc \;
```

Answer (score 1):

From `cp` man page:

```
cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST
cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY
cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...
```

You are giving parameters to `cp` in wrong order. Source should come before destination. Correct command is :

```
find / -type f -perm a+r -exec cp {} /home/student/abc \;
```

Also note that you should end -exec parameter with `;`

Comment: I tried but it did not work and I attached a new picture there

Comment: If you want to see what is being done, you should use `cp` with `-v` parameter